# How to bring a jsp into an existing modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, modal-dialog

I have a modal window called kmodal, which has some links in it. When i click one link, it provides me with an accept button. Now when i click this button, i have to bring my jsp within this modal without closing it and i have to get rid of other links without disturbing the lay out. How can i achieve this ?

I tried this one :

```
        jQuery('#button').load('myJSP', function() {
        jQuery(this).show();
```

But this does not work.
Can any one suggest any ideas here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do load without the callback function - and you don't want to load the jsp inside your button.. You want it in the modal.  You can read more about [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) here

```
jQuery('yourmodalcontainer').on('click','#button',function(){
    jQuery('yourmodalcontainer').load('myJSP');
    // this will load your jsp into the modal
});
```

My example uses delegation as I don't know how/when your button is created

You need to use delegation when your elements don't exist in the dom at the time of binding..  So I'm actually not sure when your modal or how it's created also.. It's best to bind to the closest parent element that is static and available at dom ready.. but to be safe you can bind it to the body

```
jQuery('body').on('click','#button',function(){
```

Comment: Don't i need to trigger this by using an onclick() for the button?
I have added the script that you have suggested inside the jsp, but it's not doing anything. Am i missing the plot here?

BTW : you are missing a single ) in your last line. :)(sheepishly)

Comment: actually I had an extra `(`.. try now.. and this is the click event for the button.. we just bind the handler to the modal container. But actually maybe you should bind it to the body. since I actually don't know when the modal is created - or if it's created dynamically also

Comment: Thanks wirey, i will try t out and let you know if this works .

Comment: Okay, this does not work for me. Due to some reason the jsp fails to load and i get a 500 error. However, i have seen that the path mentioned is correct , so no problem with the path. However, since the jsp contained little content so i brought everything inside my parent jsp modal.Then depending on the user click  i am setting the display:none for the other different   divs and showing the only one  that matters. That's how i could make it work .